# Is it possible to add custom Sprite to the mouse cursor in cocos creator

Tags: cocoscreator

I want to add my own image ad a sprite to the cursor in cocos creator.

If there is any other alternate solution which can achieve this, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna assume that you're using Cocos Creator 3 and that you are making a build for the browser.

One potential way I can offer for adding a custom image to your cursor is to grab the [`canvas`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_canvas.asp) element that renders the whole game and modify it's [`cursor`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp) CSS property.

## Example

```
import { _decorator, Component, ImageAsset } from 'cc';
const { ccclass, property } = _decorator;

@ccclass('TestScript')
export class TestScript extends Component
{
    @property(ImageAsset)
    private cursorImage : ImageAsset = null;

    start ()
    {
        const canvas = document.getElementById("GameCanvas");
        canvas.style.cursor = `url("${this.cursorImage.nativeUrl}"), auto`;
    }
}
```